# Help with a theorem in Hungerford's book

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm trying to understand a theorem of [Hungerford's book](http://libgen.org/get?nametype=orig&md5=3CF13F219E5121470C6D659A9AB9F46C)

First, Hungerford defines a localization in the following manner:

[image]

After that, there is a theorem:

[image]

I have just a little doubt with this theorem, I didn't understand why $Q\subset P$ in the fourth line.

It's just a detail, but it's a crucial point in the core of the proof.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just part (i) which was proven before. Since there is a one-to-one correspondence between the set of prime ideals of $R$ which are contained in $P$ and the set of prime ideals of $R_P$, the maximal ideal $M$ has a preimage $Q$, i.e. $M=Q_P$ and this $Q$ is contained in $P$, in symbols $Q\subset P$.

Comment: yes, of course, thank you